# Неправильный роут по дефолту?

Tags: роутинг, маршрутизация, kohana

Не пойму в чем дело, роуты:

```
Route::set('object','(objects/test/<mod>(/<id>))',
    array(
        'mod'=>('change')
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'objects',
        'action' => 'edit',
    ));

Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'main',
        'action' => 'index',
    ));
```

В итоге при входе на сайт попадаю в 1-ый роут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что первый роут у вас в скобках, что говорит о том, что он срабатывает и с пустым запросом. Приоритет верхних маршрутов выше.

Решение: убрать скобки.

```
Route::set('object','objects/test/<mod>(/<id>)',
// и т.д.
```

Comment: действительно!

Answer (score 1):

Kohana берёт первый совпадающий роут просто. А 1й роут у Вас неверно написан. Скобка не там. Надо, если я не ошибаюсь, так:

```
Route::set('object','objects/test(/<mod>(/<id>))',
    array(
        'mod'=>'(change)'
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'objects',
        'action' => 'edit',
    ));
```

но я не очень понимаю чего вы этим роутом хотите добиться и куда попасть

Comment: да, и вы правы.